# Regex.IsMatch return false

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application where my users have a possibility to write comments.
But I want filter insults with special characters.

```
string comment = "Ðick"; // With special "Ð".

comment = Regex.Replace(comment, @"[^a-z0-9 ]", "[a-z]"); // Replace special char by "[a-z]"
Regex regex = new Regex(@""+comment +""); // @"[a-z]ick"

return (regex.IsMatch("dick")) ? true : false;
```

When the comment is only "Ðick" the function returns true, but if the comment is "Ðick with another word" the function returns false. Why?

Comment: What is the value of `comment` after `Replace()`?

Comment: see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It might be easier to simply disallow all 'special' characters.

Comment: IsMatch returns true for me... I just test your very same code.

Comment: *"Trying to make a bad word filter is a waste of time."* Rolf van Dick

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is often done with a Canonical decomposition plus the stripping of the "Combining Diacritical Marks". You can't do it with pure regex... and even having a little C# you have to do it manually for some characters (like for example `Ð` to `D` or `Ø` to `O`). For some other characters you can do it in a more "automated" way (like `è` to `e`) using the `string.Normalize`, like:

```
string comment = "Ðè";

// Here we split (è) to U+0065 (e) U+0300 (̀)
string commentNormalized = comment.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

// Here we remove all the UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark
// that are the diacritics like U+0300 (̀)
// and rebuild the string. This line can be speedup a little, but
// it would be longer to write :-)
string comment2 = new string(commentNormalized.Where(x => char.GetUnicodeCategory(x) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray());
```

Now `comment2` is `"Ðe"`.

This because [è](http://chars.suikawiki.org/string?s=%C3%A8) has a "Canonical decomposition" `U+0065 (e) U+0300 (̀)`, so you can find that `è` is "similar" to `e`, while for [Ð](http://chars.suikawiki.org/string?s=%C3%90) it's "Canonical decomposition" is still `U+00D0 (Ð)` so the same character.

What you are trying to do is futile: when you ban a character, the users will find another "similar" character... have you ever heard of [Leet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)? Is `D1ck` (`1` instead of `i`) better than your word? :-)

It is normally better to have a dictionary of "banned words", that has both `Dork` and `Ðork`, and when you find a new permutation of an "offensive" word, you simply add it. Human fantasy is infinite... so must be your dictionary :-) but one word at a time.

Comment: Thanks, i'll bring myself to disallow special characters.

Comment: @LaurieCos It is still a *stupd* idea :-) You will still have *d1ck* users, even without special characters. and language has more information than necessary... you can remove one or two letters from a word and 90% of the persons will still be able to comprehend the word.